# Looking for a fast way, to represent the value of an integer, by a number in the range 0 to 3 (without branching?)

Tags: vb.net, integer, numbers, byte

Given that **val** is some random integer,

and number the possible outcome:

if the **value** is less then &H100 ; the number is 0

if the **value** is less then &H10000 ; the number is 1

if the **value** is less then &H1000000 ; the number is 2

else ; the number is 3

I've got this:

```
      If (val And &HFFFF0000) = 0 Then
            If (val And &HFF00) = 0 Then
                num = 0
            Else
               numb = 1
            End If
        ElseIf (**val** And &HFF000000) = 0 Then
             numb = 2
        Else
             numb = 3
        End If
```

I believe to  remember that I could achieve this with a simple calculation, but I can not
wrap my head around it...

cheers..
Jhonny

edit:--- after reaction of video.baba ---

Here is half a solution:

The result is a number from 0 to 7, of witch the bits represent a non-zero byte.
A lookuptable could be used to translate it to a 2-bit value.

```
val >>= 8   ' move to the right, so the first byte can hold identification-bits
val += &H3FF0000 'set a bit in the first byte, if the second one is not zero
val = val And &H400FFFF
val += &H1FFFF00    'set a bit in the first byte, if the third one is not zero
val = val And &H60000FF
val += &HFFFFFF'set a bit in the first byte, if the fourth one is not zero
val >>= 24  'put the result in the last byte
number=lookuptable(val)
```

have not tested it for speed yet, but it feels over-complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
    Select Case Value
        Case < &H100
            Number = 0
        Case < &H10000
            Number = 1
        Case < &H1000000
            Number = 2
        Case Else
            Number = 3
    End Select
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking along. But no. Select-case is a fancy way of doing an ordinairy if-then-tree. I'm looking for a math-solution. I had a way in an other BASIC, that used the carry-bit in a rotational shift. (Trying to do something similar...)